# Javascript - Getting only 10 items from list column

Tags: list, javascript, lookup-column

I have a custom code to get data from a second list, this list returns some columns, but this code is getting only 10 values even tho the list have a lot more than that. I got this code from a microsoft website some time ago and I modified it.

Code:

```
function retrieveListItems() {

  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
  var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Adicionar favorecidos');

  var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
  camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
  this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

  clientContext.load(collListItem);

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceededed), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFaileded));

}

function onQuerySucceededed(sender, args) {


  var listItemInfo = '';
  var arrayCNPJ = '';
  var agencia = '';
  var contaBancaria = '';
  var chaveDoBanco = '';
  var valorLiquido = '';
  var valorBruto = '';


  var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

  while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += ";" + oListItem.get_item('Title');
    arrayCNPJ += ";" + oListItem.get_item('CNPJ');
    agencia += ";" + oListItem.get_item('Agencia');
    conta += ";" + oListItem.get_item('ContaBancaria');
    chaveDoBanco += ";" + oListItem.get_item('ChaveDoBanco');
  }

  window.arrayItem = listItemInfo.split(";");
  window.arrayCNPJFormatado = arrayCNPJ.split(";");
  window.agenciawindow = agencia.split(";");
  window.contawindow = conta.split(";");
  window.chaveDoBancoWindow = chaveDoBanco.split(";");


  $('#favorecidoSelect').select2();
  $('.selectMaterialize').formSelect();

  $('#favorecidoSelect').on('contentChanged', function () {
    $(this).select2();
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayItem.length; i++) {
    $('#favorecidoSelect').append('<option value=' + i + '>' + arrayItem[i] + '</option>');
    $("#favorecidoSelect").trigger('contentChanged');
  }

  //alert(listItemInfo.toString());
}

function onQueryFaileded(sender, args) {

  alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only getting 10 because you're only asking for 10.

`<RowLimit>10</RowLimit>`

Comment: didn't notice that, really dumb mistake. I got this code from microsoft and I really don't know how it works.Well, thank you and happy new year!